# create a dictionary value key from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe :

```
PageId      OSBrowser
1005581     (11, 16)
1016529     (11, 16)
1016529     (11, 17)
1016529     (12, 14)
1016529     (12, 16)
```

I am trying to create a dictionary dico : where the key is the OSBrowser value and PageID are the list for each key value :

So the expected result should be :

```
#key          #values 
(11, 16)       1005581, 1016529
(11, 17)       1016529
(12, 14)       1016529
(12, 16)       1016529
```

I try with this code :

```
dico = {}
for row in data:
    tup = data['OSBrowser']
    print(tup)
    if tup not in dico:
        dico[tup] = []
        dico[tup].append(row['PageId'])
        [print(f"{key} : {value}") for key, value in dico.items()]
```

But I got this error :

```
----> 5     if tup not in dico:
      6         dico[tup] = []
      7         dico[tup].append(row['PageId'])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

Can you help me to fix it please?

Thank you

Comment: in the given example of expected result values are shown as strings, but in your code it actualy lists. So what do you realy expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `df.index` to traverse through the dataframe

```
d = {}
for ind in data.index:
    page_id = data["PageId"][ind]
    os_browser = data["OSBrowser"][ind]
    if os_browser not in d:
        d[os_browser] = [page_id]
    else:
        d[os_browser].append(page_id)
```

Comment: thank you , but your solution gave me the inverted output :  i need gor each OSBrowser, the list of PageId

Comment: Just noticed it was supposed to be the other way around. You can update the loop accordingly and get the desired dict

Comment: can you edit your response please with the correct form? thanks

Comment: Done, can you check if it works?

Comment: although it works, I think it is a little slow. If you have a pandas series why do not take advantage from the pandas library?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you define a series like:

```
s = pd.Series([(11, 16),(11, 16),(11, 17),(12, 14),(12, 14)], index=[1005581,1016529,1016529,1016529,1016529])
```

you can obtain you expected output with:

```
s.to_frame().reset_index().groupby(0)["index"].unique()
```